# Why does non-proportional scaling cause a problem on a printing press?

Tags: print-design, resize, prepress

I'm in prepress and for a long time I have know that it is a no-no to have images non-proportionally scaled but no one has ever explained why? Does it error out when it gets to the RIP? What is the problem with stretching an image just a little bit more in one direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixels are square... non-square pixels (stretched or squished pixels) degrade the image quality. The degradation is not always overly noticeable, but it's always there.

The standard guideline to never "stretch or squish" a raster image is merely "good practice". It's similar to always requiring 300ppi, when in reality 240ppi is sufficient in most instances.

In short, it's not really a technical issue which may cause problems with a RIP or anything. It's just good practice if the desire is to deliver a quality product.

Comment: Image quality is one thing. If the image is high enough resolution, I'm not sure you can really say stretching affects image quality as such. But stretched images are just ugly. You can look so long at an image that you get used to a stretched face, but when you revert to correct aspect ratio it becomes very clear how wrong it looked before.

Comment: It *does* effect the quality @Wolff but, admittedly the effect can be so minute if the "stretch" is slight, it may be largely unnoticeable with the naked eye. But for *pre-press*, a standard rule to *never* stretch or squish images is merely good customer service - otherwise you get that employee that does it randomly without concern and causes issues.

Comment: Thank you Scott and Wolff for your answers. I don't ever stretch an image but tend to get files from a customer that does this all the time.